# What is the most fundamental way to maintain a filtered ObservableList?

Tags: java, collections, javafx

Suppose you have a list of objects of a base type (in my case, `NotebookEntry`), and this list contains objects of various descendant types (like `NotebookEntryPlainText`). This master `ObservableList<NotebookEntry>` is maintained by the notebook manager, but various controls will need to create their own filtered lists from that master list - say, only plain text entries. These lists must include all entries applicable that are in the master list, but if an entry is removed from the master list, those lists must not contain it.

I have come up with a binding extending `ListBinding`, which avoids having to implement any listeners. The binding is one-directional on purpose.

The code is very simple:

```
public class ObservableFilteredList<T> extends ListBinding<T>
{
    private final ObservableList<T> masterlist;
    private final Predicate<T> predicate;

    public ObservableFilteredList(ObservableList<T> _masterlist, Predicate<T> _p)
    {
        masterlist = _masterlist;
        predicate = _p;
        super.bind(masterlist);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        super.unbind(masterlist);
    }

    @Override
    protected ObservableList<T> computeValue()
    {
        return FXCollections.observableList(
                masterlist.parallelStream()
                .filter(predicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                );
    }
}
```

Is this the most elegant way to achieve this function? Is this already implemented in JDK 8? I have looked, but maybe I wasn't searching with the correct question.

A sample implementation:

```
    ObservableList<String> sourcelist;
    ObservableFilteredList<String> filteredlist;

    sourcelist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    listview_source.setItems(sourcelist);

    filteredlist = new ObservableFilteredList<String>(sourcelist, s -> s.toUpperCase().startsWith("O"));
    listview_filtered.setItems(filteredlist);
```

What are the downsides of this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is already implemented and is known as [FilteredList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html), you can obtain it with
[ObservableList.filtered(Predicate)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#filtered-java.util.function.Predicate-) or you can create your own `FilteredList` wrapping the existing `ObservableList` + setting the correct [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html).

Comment: It was staring me in the face the whole time from the context menu.